# Is there an issue with my use of pygame.rect.move?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am using `pygame.rect.move()` to move a button to a certain position on instantiation. Then from the list of objects to blit that exists the menu button is called and all functions that need to be called each frame. The button does NOT move.

The rect should perfectly fit the button.

Is my use of `pygame.rect.move()` incorrect?

Here's the class:

```
class menuButton(mainMenu):
    def setpos(self):
        self.r = self.r.move(self.p)
    def __init__(self,i,e,s,p, ai, ao,sa):
        self.t = "Menu Button"
        self.i = pygame.image.load(i)
        self.r = self.i.get_rect()
        self.e = e
        self.ai = ai
        self.ao = ao
        self.p = p
        self.a = 0
        self.i.set_alpha(sa)
        pygame.transform.scale(self.i,s)
        objects.append(self)
        print "%s has been instantiated." % (self.t)
    def logic(self):
        pass
    def animations(self):
        if self.ai == "FADE_IN":
            if(self.i.get_alpha() < 255):
                self.i.set_alpha(self.i.get_alpha() + 1)

    def update(self):
        self.r = self.i.get_rect()
        r = True
        for obj in objects:
            if isinstance(self,type(obj)) == False:
                r = False
        if r == True:
            if self.a == 0:
                self.setpos()
                print self.r
            self.a += 1
            self.logic()
            self.animations()
            screen.blit(self.i,self.r)
            pygame.display.flip()
```

I'm not using .convert() at the end of an image import because it breaks the images.
I'm not using sprites because I want more control.
I have also written test programs and it seems to have worked, and I've re-written the main menu button class 3 times. Same issue.

Comment: There is a `{}` button on the editor toolbar that indents code for you.

Answer (score 1):

> m not using .convert() at the end of an image import because it breaks the images.

In what way? You probably want the alpha version http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha

> I'm not using sprites because I want more control.

You can derive from `Sprite` , then you can add anything you want, yet still use `sprite.Group`s

A side note on the names, a Menu would contain Buttons. But buttons deriving from menu doesn't make sense.

`move()` returns a new rect that has moved, `move_ip()` modifies the existing rect.

Or you can use the rect properties

```
def setpos(self):
    self.r.topleft = self.p
```

What are you doing with this code?

```
    r = True
    for obj in objects:
        if isinstance(self,type(obj)) == False:
            r = False
    if r == True:
        if self.a == 0:
            self.setpos()
            print self.r
        self.a += 1
```

Comment: Thank-you for convert_alpha(). I prefer having raw control, as having a sprite means I have more attributes than I need or less than I am going to need. The buttons derive from the menu not to inherit any methods, but to show the code in the update() method if the object currently existing is an instance of this. The button is thus an instance of menu so r remains unchanged. I took the easy way out on that one. The code at the bottom is a set of rules for blitting. If self is not an instance of the object, don't render. self.a = a. setpos was merely experimental.

Comment: convert_alpha seems to prevent me from changing the alpha of a surface. Also, moving an object in place has not solved my problem.

Comment: What are you using that code block for? Do you want per pixel alpha, or single value for the entire surface? or a single color set to transparent? Those are 3 different modes.

Comment: I need ppa to be formatted into one value. By default without conversion it seems to do the trick, though it isn't really doing that. When I say formatted into one value, each one has an abstract value which has an amount deducted from it which is thus deducted from the actual alpha itself.